# PHP date in filename - HTML PAGE

Tags: php, date, filenames

How can I print the php-date as filename?

```
if(file_exists('../folder1/folder2/d-m-Y.txt')) {include '../folder1/folder2/d-m-Y.txt';} ...
```

The PHP code is embedded in an HTML page.

Comment: *"The PHP code is embedded in an HTML page."* - Hmm..... Big question mark for me here.

Comment: `if(file_exists('../folder1/folder2/m-d-Y.txt';'))` there's a stray quote there btw; that alone would have thrown a parse error. Question's too unclear for me.

Comment: Voted to close as unclear. I don't know which animal(s) I'm really dealing with here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
$date = date("m-d-Y");
if(file_exists("../folder1/folder2/{$date}.txt"))
{
   # do something
}
```

---

Curly braces are optional but help code readability, you can also use it like:

```
"../folder1/folder2/$date.txt"
```

Comment: I left a few comments under the question. This thing's just too unclear for me.

Comment: Right on :-) Glad to see this was as easy as that.